# Can't get jQuery accordion to work for WordPress posts

Tags: jquery, wordpress, accordion

I enqueued `jquery-ui-accordion` in the header, and included the following function to activate it:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
});
```

Below is how the html is set up. The output is just a list of regular WordPress posts without any accordion functionality. I would like it so that the title becomes clickable. Can someone help me figure out what I did wrong?

```
    <?php get_header();?>

        <section id="content">

            <h2>Our Latest Videos</h2>

            <section id="latest-videos" class="video-archive">
                <section id="accordion">

                    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                    <article class="entry" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                        <section class="description">
                            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                            <div>
                                test test test
                            </div>
                        </section>
                    </article>

                <?php endwhile; ?>

                <?php endif; ?>

                </section>

            </section>

        </section>

    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the html markup is somewhat like this:

```
<section id="accordion">
  <article>
    <section class="description">
      <h3>First header</h3>
      <div>First content panel</div>
    </section>
  </article>
  <article>
    <section class="description">
      <h3>Second header</h3>
      <div>Second content panel</div>
    </section>
  </article>
</section>
```

Then, `accordion` will not work. For it to work you need to have only pairs of `<h3>` and `<div>` inside the `<section>` like below:

```
<section id="accordion">
 <h3>First header</h3>
 <div>First content panel</div>
 <h3>Second header</h3>
 <div>Second content panel</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

What does the output of this look like? You might want to take the standard markup generated in your browser, then implement the accordion. That way you not only have confirmed that it works the way you want it to, but you will have a better understanding of the plug-in. After that porting it over to wp should be pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

Don't take it Hard ! it can be Valid while wrapped in **`<article>`** !
you Wrap it on `<article>` and then on your **js code** add the following parameter :

```
    $('#accordion').accordion({
       header: "article h3",
     });
```

as you noticed , you just have to put the **header** new position in parameters ! which is a **child** of article tag :)